# XSL - Sum of the value of elements

Tags: xml, xslt

I have one `XML` file :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
    <File>
        <Cars>
            <Car>
                <Color>Blue</Color>
                <Year>1988</Year>
                <Quantity>150</Quantity>
            </Car>
            <Car>
                <Color>Green</Color>
                <Year>1989</Year>
                <Quantity>200</Quantity>
            </Car>
        </Cars>
    </File>
```

And one `XSL` file :

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="utf-8" media-type="text/xml"/>

    <xsl:template match="File">
        <File>

            <vehicles>
                <xsl:for-each select="Cars/Car">
                    <vehicle>
                        <vehicleColor>
                            <xsl:value-of select="Color"/>
                        </vehicleColor>
                        <vehicleYear>
                            <xsl:value-of select="Year"/>
                        </vehicleYear>
                    </vehicle>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </vehicles>

            <TotalQuantity>
                    <xsl:value-of select="sum()"/> ///// Sum of quantity of all car (<Quantity>)
            </TotalQuantity>
        </File>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I want to make the sum of all quantities of each car and display the result in element `TotalQuantity`. What to put in sum() method ?

I use only the `XSL` 1.0. I transform my `XML` with `XslCompiledTransform` class c#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your current node is `File`, you want:

```
sum(Cars/Car/Quantity)
```

of course.

Comment: Quite simply... Thanks!

Comment: Is that all the XPath features are available with XSL 1.0 ?  http://www.tutorialspoint.com/xpath/index.htm Axes, Operators,Wildcard, Predicate etc

Comment: All the XPath 1.0 features are described in the official documentation: https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#contents